# Rails 5 Foundation 6 not loading css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I cannot get foundation + rails working. I've installed foundation gem without problems and when I create simple page with foundation content it can't load stylesheets.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Untitled" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
      <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
          <h1><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
        </li>
         <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li>
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Right Button Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">First link in dropdown</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Left Nav Section -->
        <ul class="left">
          <li><a href="#">Left Nav Button</a></li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
    <%= yield %>

  </body>
```

Rails version: 5.0.2

Foundation: 6.3.1.0

Any ideas how to get this working ?

Comment: I would take a look at this here, it sounds like you're having an asset pipeline issue. Make sure that you're importing it properly to your application.css file.
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails#foundationrails

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think its importing properly. Inside application.css I have found require declaration. '/*= require foundation_and_overrides'

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server, run `rails g foundation:install`, and start it again

Comment: I did that during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue working with rails 5 and foundation 6. It had been a while since last using rails and I was a bit rusty. I had spent a good couple of hours scratching my head and searching the net.

I use rvm to keep all of my gems seperate so decided to take a look in my gemset and found that I had two versions of the gem installed:

`foundation-rails-5.4.5.0/` and `foundation-rails-6.4.1.3/`

After removing version `5.4.5.0` I ran the `rails g foundation:install` command again, this fixed the issue.

I assume I ran the installer using the older version which generates a completely different `foundation_and_overrides.scss` file to the new version.

this is what the new version looks like:

```
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';

// If you'd like to include motion-ui the foundation-rails gem comes prepackaged with it, uncomment the 3 @imports, if you are not using the gem you need to install the motion-ui sass package.
//
// @import 'motion-ui/motion-ui';

// We include everything by default.  To slim your CSS, remove components you don't use.

@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-xy-grid-classes;
//@include foundation-grid;
//@include foundation-flex-grid;
@include foundation-flex-classes;
@include foundation-typography;
@include foundation-forms;
@include foundation-button;
@include foundation-accordion;
@include foundation-accordion-menu;
@include foundation-badge;
@include foundation-breadcrumbs;
@include foundation-button-group;
@include foundation-callout;
@include foundation-card;
@include foundation-close-button;
@include foundation-menu;
@include foundation-menu-icon;
@include foundation-drilldown-menu;
@include foundation-dropdown;
@include foundation-dropdown-menu;
@include foundation-responsive-embed;
@include foundation-label;
@include foundation-media-object;
@include foundation-off-canvas;
@include foundation-orbit;
@include foundation-pagination;
@include foundation-progress-bar;
@include foundation-slider;
@include foundation-sticky;
@include foundation-reveal;
@include foundation-switch;
@include foundation-table;
@include foundation-tabs;
@include foundation-thumbnail;
@include foundation-title-bar;
@include foundation-tooltip;
@include foundation-top-bar;
@include foundation-visibility-classes;
@include foundation-float-classes;

// If you'd like to include motion-ui the foundation-rails gem comes prepackaged with it, uncomment the 3 @imports, if you are not using the gem you need to install the motion-ui sass package.
//
// @include motion-ui-transitions;
// @include motion-ui-animations;
```

The older version was largely commented out variable declarations and only inlcluded two uncommented imports:

```
@import 'foundation/functions' //which gave a file not found error
@import 'foundation'
```

Hopefully this will help others in this situation.